# Entering dates in a form field

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to enter a form in https://www.wg-gesucht.de/en/ and the subsequent link using selenium. The following is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver

URL = "https://www.wg-gesucht.de/en/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(URL)

#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='date_from_input']").send_keys('31/08/2017')
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='date_to_input']").send_keys('01/09/2017')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='autocompinp']").send_keys('Berlin')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='rubrik-dropdown-menu']").click()
l1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@data-text='Flatshares']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", l1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='ang-ges-dropdown-menu']").click()
l2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@data-text='Offers']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", l2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='search_button']").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='rMax']").send_keys('400')
cmd_d1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='date_from_input']").value= '31/08/2017'
driver.execute_script(cmd_d1)
cmd_d2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='date_to_input']").value = '01/09/2017'
driver.execute_script(cmd_d2)
```

It works perfectly, except for the dates fields which are hidden in the `More Options` button. How do I insert the values?

Comment: post relevent html pls

Comment: The html is too big

Comment: http://www.wg-gesucht.de/en/wg-zimmer-in-Berlin.8.0.1.0.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1** - click on 'More Options' click to expand the panle, to make date input fields visible

```
// click 'More Options' click
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.show_more_filters').click()
// input begin date
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#date_from_input').send_keys('31/08/2017')
// input end date
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#date_to_input').send_keys('01/09/2017')
```

**Shortage**: send_keys() maybe trigger datepicker pop-up and won't close it proper,
the not closed datepicker will block input below address and distance text box

**Option 2** - use execute_script() to inject and execute javascript on browser to set value of date input field act as silent way.

```
// click 'More Options' click
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.show_more_filters').click()
// input begin date
begin_date_ele = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#date_from_input')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value=arguments[1]', begin_date_ele, '31/08/2017')

// input end date
end_date_ele = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#date_to_input')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value=arguments[1]', end_date_ele, '01/09/2017')
```

Comment: Thanks. The second option works every time. However, the submit does not work `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='filter_submit_button']").click()`

Comment: driver.finde_element_by_css_selector('button.filter_submit_button').click()

Comment: recommend to use css selector as first option, unless css selector can't resolve your problem, then xpath is the second option.  css selector is simple and short than xpath to locator same element and css selector fast than xpath to locator element from page.

Comment: ok. changed the code, but it keeps saying the button can not be located

Comment: try this string again 'button.filter_submit_button', it's strange the both string look same, but the first one on above comment can't find the button.   if the second one also can't find, please use  find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'filter_submit_button')]"')

Comment: It works. But now strangely the date filters get erased after submission.

Comment: Yes, I reproduced it by manual. The reason is we set the date by changing input box value with silent way, this way won't trigger the click event of datepicker.  I guess when you choose and click one date from datepicker, the click event binds to a javascript function writen by developer, this function will store the choosen date in somewhere, maybe windows global variable or browser local storage.  But the silent way won't trigger the click event.  If this site developed by your company, you can discuss with the developer to find out how to make the value be saved as choose date by manual